# Why was Michael Scott forgotten so easily?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

Michael Scott, a Dunder Mifflin employee for 19 years and was with these employees for more than 10 years. (correct me if I am wrong)
But as he left the office suddenly to move to Colorado, he was instantly forgotten too. The office just moves on with new boss and later new CEO and never have another Michael Scott moment again.

One would think that Michael Scott had so much influence on these people's lives and he was so so much involved in their lives (despite their annoyance at times) the office would not forget him so easily. He would be remembered, mentioned often. One employee would randomly mention he talked to Michael or an update on Michael's life is shared. Strangely none of that happened until the very last episode.

In the last episode, it is mentioned he is married and has four kids. Quite strange actually, as no one was invited to his wedding and not a single employee knew he is married and has kids. not even his confidant Dwight, his Best friends Jim and Ryan or his favorite female friend Pam.

What could be the reason for this? was the office so annoyed by him that everyone was just happy he left and never cared about him ever again?

Comment: It's a sitcom, not a documentary. They've got about 22 minutes, in which they have to cram several plots and plenty of jokes. There is no time to randomly reminisce about a character that has left the show weeks/months/years ago, and there is no point to it.

Comment: There must be a tv tropes entry for how characters are never mentioned after they leave the show. It's common in pretty much every show.

Comment: @GendoIkari: Yes, there is, I remember reading it. No, I don't remember the trope's name. **NO, I WILL NOT LOOK IT UP** I have things to do today :-D

Comment: Your last sentence sums it up; he made no lasting bond with anyone on the show, except maybe Holly.  None of the other characters enjoyed his presence.

Comment: I think the way the office helped him propose to Holly along with his goodbye episode is proof positive that he made a lasting impression on every person in the office. His entire arc is about the journey from hateful douche to a lovable eccentric. Why wasn't he mentioned in later episodes? Because the show lost their flagship character and the writers didn't want to call attention to his absence, IMO. Luckily for me, I enjoyed Robert California's weirdness almost as much as Scott's ridiculousness, although I understand critics disliked the later seasons; not sure why.

Comment: It could also be they don't want the audience to anticipate the return of Michael Scott. If they planted a few lines through out the seasons about MS, people might get excited and believe they are building to his return. It might also ruin what fans think happened to MS after he left. Pam confirms he left happy and couldn't wait to see Holly, that's all we the fans needed to hear about MS, nothing more. We can just imagine what he is up to, and that's part of the fun, given MS and his antics. In the last eps, it's confirmed he got married and has kids, that was enough given it was the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep in mind that we do not see a full working day.

Assuming that we see the episode's 20 minutes runtime as uninterrupted work time footage (with no concurrent scenes shown one after the other), that's still only **4.2%** of a work day. We're not seeing 95.8% of a work day.
And this is assuming that we could keep an eye on every character at the same time. Since we realistically can't (unless they're all grouped together, which is not the case for the majority of time), this further lowers the amount of footage we actually get to see from a given work day.

Reminiscing about Michael is either relevant to the plot, or it is not relevant to the plot. If it is not relevant to the plot, then there's no need to display it as it is a waste of screen time.

Reminiscing about Michael can only be relevant to the plot in cases where Steve Carell doesn't need to appear anymore. E.g. if Dwight went through an emo phase due to missing Michael, it would've been relevant to reminisce about Michael *for Dwight's storyline*.

However, since there were no (sub)plots involving characters dealing with Michael's absence; there was no reason to bring up Michael's absence again.